# Protractor throwing .key is undefined

Tags: webdriver, protractor

I have a test that needs a delete key to be simulated into a input field. I have tried using

```
element.sendKeys(protractor.keys.delete);
```

and

```
browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.DELETE).perform();
```

The error being thrown states .key is undefined.  Any thoughts?

Comment: `browser.actions().sendKeys(protractor.Key.DELETE).perform();` This works well in my tests. Maybe something else is wrong.

Comment: Can you try moving the focus to input field before performing delete operation. `browser.actions().click(inputElement).sendKeys(protractor.Key.DELETE).perform();`

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs of protractor](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.sendKeys) the syntax should be this

```
element.sendKeys(protractor.Key.DELETE);
```

The keys can be found [here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Keys.html)

Hope it helps.

Comment: No, according to the docs, this is actually `protractor.Key` (no s at the end).

Comment: Sorry, typo, fixed it

Comment: Why the downvote? This is the way to use the `Key`s, if it is not working it could be a wrong code implementation or a webdriver issue

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use `element.sendKeys('\b')`

Try console logging "protractor" and seeing if it is null or undefined. In my hazy experience, if an object is undefined, calling a variable from that object will throw `variable is undefined` instead of saying `object is undefined`.